# Warning: openssl_x509_read(): supplied parameter cannot be coerced into an X509 certificate on Mac

Tags: ios, openssl, x509certificate

I tried to create signature using certificate on mac:

```
$pkcs12 = file_get_contents($this->certPath);

$certs = array();

if(openssl_pkcs12_read($pkcs12, $certs, $this->certPass) == true) {

    $certdata = openssl_x509_read($certs['cert']);
    $privkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs['pkey'], $this->certPass );

    openssl_pkcs7_sign($paths['manifest'], $paths['signature'], $certdata, $privkey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED);

    $signature = file_get_contents($paths['signature']);
    $signature = $this->convertPEMtoDER($signature);

    file_put_contents($paths['signature'], $signature);

    return true;
}
```

But it gives me:

> Warning: openssl_x509_read(): supplied parameter cannot be coerced
>   into         an X509 certificate!

I've found someone saying it is the UTF-8 BOM issue but it is not the issue in this case, how should I do?

Thanks!